# Does the Fill Factor setting affect heaps / heap tables with non-clustered indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, nonclustered-index, fill-factor, heap

I came across this old article on Brent Ozar's blog (written by Kendra Little) regarding Fill Factor: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/

In it, she briefly mentions that the Fill Factor setting does not affect Heaps.

Does this still apply today, and does she mean only pure heaps that don't even have non-clustered indexes?...or to any heap table regardless if it has non-clustered indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-clustered indexes on a heap will use the fill factor, but a heap is not an index (although it does appear in `sys.indexes`).

Since there is no way to reorganize a heap it can't have a fill factor. Fill factor only comes into the picture when rebuilding or creating an index; it only applies to indexes.

I believe [How Forwarded Records are Read and Processed in a SQL Server Heap](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-forwarded-records-are-read-and-processed-in-a-sql-server-heap/) by Uwe Ricken may help you out. Specifically regarding how SQL Server uses PFS to determine inserts for records into the heap, and also how a non-clustered index uses the RID in relation to the heap.